# Fabric.js Font Family not working on touch devices

Tags: fabricjs

Below mentioned code is working fine on Window 7 browsers but not changing the font family in touch devices' browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ConvertIntoSignature()//
{
var FirstName = $('#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').val();//
var SecondName = $('#<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>').val();//

if (FirstName != '' || SecondName != '') {
var text = '';
text = FirstName + ' ' + SecondName;
// I am using 4 canvas for this purpose.

var can = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");
// This is the fabric code
// Its working for window 7 browsers. But not on any touch devices

var txt = new fabric.Text(text, {
fontFamily: 'Brush Script MT'
});
can.add(txt);

}
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Find any solution so far?

Comment: Please check the following answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used the external font families.

Example

```
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format).</p>

</body>
```

For external font families used this link http://fontsforweb.com.

In my case, just use

```
var txt = new fabric.Text(text, {
fontFamily: myFirstFont
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If fonts are already loaded then still not updating fontFamily then use this trick.

Reassign text again to text property and render

```
 var obj =  this.canvas.getActiveObject();
 obj.set('fontFamily','Arial');
 obj.text = obj.text;  
 this.canvas.renderAll();
```

If above not working then concat some string to text and render and then remove that string and render again.

```
 var obj =  this.canvas.getActiveObject();
 obj.set('fontFamily','Arial');
 obj.text = obj.text+" ";  
 this.canvas.renderAll();  
 obj.text = obj.text;  
 this.canvas.renderAll();
```

Note: This fixed my issue of not changing fontFamily when applied.